# HTML Centering image and h1 inside a card

Tags: html, css

I need help centering the image and h1 inside a card I have created. I want them to be next to eachother and centered horizontally.

https://jsfiddle.net/1tjpnvdt/

I have tried things with floats and not have gotten it to work. I have gotten them on the same line but not able to center them.

```
<section class="workers-section">
            <h2 class="section-heading">Töötajad</h2>
            <table class="workers_table">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="mainbox">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img class="profile_pic" src="workers/default.jpg" alt="default">
                                <h1 class="name">Name</h1>
                                <p class="work"><span class="work_icon"> </span>Work</p>
                                <p class="mail"><span class="mail_icon">✉ </span>Email</p>
                                <p class="phone"><span class="phone_icon">✆ </span>Phone</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="mainbox">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img class="profile_pic" src="workers/default.jpg" alt="default" />
                                <h1 class="name">Name</h1>
                                <p class="work"><span class="work_icon"> </span>Work</p>
                                <p class="mail"><span class="mail_icon">✉ </span>Email</p>
                                <p class="phone"><span class="phone_icon">✆ </span>Phone</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="mainbox">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img class="profile_pic" src="workers/default.jpg" alt="default" />
                                <h1 class="name">Name</h1>
                                <p class="work"><span class="work_icon"> </span>Work</p>
                                <p class="mail"><span class="mail_icon">✉ </span>Email</p>
                                <p class="phone"><span class="phone_icon">✆ </span>Phone</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="mainbox">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img class="profile_pic" src="workers/default.jpg" alt="default" />
                                <h1 class="name">Name</h1>
                                <p class="work"><span class="work_icon"> </span>Work</p>
                                <p class="mail"><span class="mail_icon">✉ </span>Email</p>
                                <p class="phone"><span class="phone_icon">✆ </span>Phone</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="mainbox">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img class="profile_pic" src="workers/default.jpg" alt="default" />
                                <h1 class="name">Name</h1>
                                <p class="work"><span class="work_icon"> </span>Work</p>
                                <p class="mail"><span class="mail_icon">✉ </span>Email</p>
                                <p class="phone"><span class="phone_icon">✆ </span>Phone</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </section>
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/1tjpnvdt/1/ ? (NOTE: change made only on first element, with inline styles) - All I've changed here is nest the `img` element within the `h1` element, removed margins and declared `vertical-align`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `div` around the image and `h1` and use flexbox to center.

```css
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card {
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  border-top: 10px solid #222;
  min-height: 250px;
  padding-: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

.work,
.mail,
.phone {
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: segoe ui;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="center">
    <img class="profile_pic" src="http://placehold.it/50" alt="Inga">
    <h1 class="name">Inga Brandmeister</h1>
  </div>
  <p class="work"><span class="work_icon"> </span>Projektijuht</p>
  <p class="mail"><span class="mail_icon">✉ </span>inga.brandmeister@frens.ee</p>
  <p class="phone"><span class="phone_icon">✆ </span>6 979 292</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is add `display: inline-block` to `.name` and `.profile_pic` – this way they are gonna be in one line. If you add `text-align: center` to `.card` – it's gonna center the content horizontally.
I also added `vertical-align: middle` to `.profile_pic` and `.name` so it's vertically centered when inline.

```js
var divs = $("td");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 3) {
  divs.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll("<td class='split_3'></td>");
}
```

```css
.card {
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  border-top: 10px solid #222;
  min-height: 250px;
  padding-: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

.profile_pic {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.name {
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.work,
.mail,
.phone {
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: segoe ui;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
}

#mainbox,
.split_3 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
  }
  td {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.workers_table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.workers-section {
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.mail_icon,
.phone_icon {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}

.work_icon {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="workers-section">
  <h2 class="section-heading">Töötajad</h2>
  <table class="workers_table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="mainbox">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="profile_pic" src="workers/inga.jpg" alt="Inga">
            <h1 class="name">Inga Brandmeister</h1>
            <p class="work"><span class="work_icon"> </span>Projektijuht</p>
            <p class="mail"><span class="mail_icon">✉ </span>inga.brandmeister@frens.ee</p>
            <p class="phone"><span class="phone_icon">✆ </span>6 979 292</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="mainbox">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="profile_pic" src="workers/kadri.jpg" alt="Kadri" />
            <h1 class="name">Kadri Eensalu</h1>
            <p class="work"><span class="work_icon"> </span>Projektijuht</p>
            <p class="mail"><span class="mail_icon">✉ </span>kadri.eensalu@frens.ee</p>
            <p class="phone"><span class="phone_icon">✆ </span>6 979 285</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="mainbox">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="profile_pic" src="workers/default.jpg" alt="Anedt" />
            <h1 class="name">Anedt Trumsi</h1>
            <p class="work"><span class="work_icon"> </span>Projektijuht</p>
            <p class="mail"><span class="mail_icon">✉ </span>anedt.trumsi@frens.ee</p>
            <p class="phone"><span class="phone_icon">✆ </span>6 979 200</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="mainbox">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="profile_pic" src="workers/default.jpg" alt="Maire" />
            <h1 class="name">Maire Linke</h1>
            <p class="work"><span class="work_icon"> </span>Peakokk</p>
            <p class="mail"><span class="mail_icon">✉ </span>maire.linke@frens.ee</p>
            <p class="phone"><span class="phone_icon">✆ </span>6064 918</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="mainbox">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="profile_pic" src="workers/tanel.jpg" alt="Tanel" />
            <h1 class="name">Tanel Vimm</h1>
            <p class="work"><span class="work_icon"> </span>Teenindus- ja logistikajuht</p>
            <p class="mail"><span class="mail_icon">✉ </span>tanel.vimm@frens.ee</p>
            <p class="phone"><span class="phone_icon">✆ </span>6 979 287</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

1st remove `default margin` top of `h1`, then change the display of `h1` to `inline-block` to align it next to `image`. Now use `text-align` center in `parent` div to align image and text in center card.

```css
.card {
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  border-top: 10px solid #222;
  min-height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

.profile_pic {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.name {
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px; /*Add this*/
  display: inline-block; /*Add this*/
}

.work,
.mail,
.phone {
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: segoe ui;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
}

#mainbox,
.split_3 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center; /*Add this*/
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
  }
  td {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.workers_table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.workers-section {
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.mail_icon,
.phone_icon {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}

.work_icon {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="workers-section">
  <h2 class="section-heading">Töötajad</h2>
  <table class="workers_table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="mainbox">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="profile_pic" src="workers/inga.jpg" alt="Inga">
            <h1 class="name">Inga Brandmeister</h1>
            <p class="work"><span class="work_icon"> </span>Projektijuht</p>
            <p class="mail"><span class="mail_icon">✉ </span>inga.brandmeister@frens.ee</p>
            <p class="phone"><span class="phone_icon">✆ </span>6 979 292</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="mainbox">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="profile_pic" src="workers/kadri.jpg" alt="Kadri" />
            <h1 class="name">Kadri Eensalu</h1>
            <p class="work"><span class="work_icon"> </span>Projektijuht</p>
            <p class="mail"><span class="mail_icon">✉ </span>kadri.eensalu@frens.ee</p>
            <p class="phone"><span class="phone_icon">✆ </span>6 979 285</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="mainbox">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="profile_pic" src="workers/default.jpg" alt="Anedt" />
            <h1 class="name">Anedt Trumsi</h1>
            <p class="work"><span class="work_icon"> </span>Projektijuht</p>
            <p class="mail"><span class="mail_icon">✉ </span>anedt.trumsi@frens.ee</p>
            <p class="phone"><span class="phone_icon">✆ </span>6 979 200</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="mainbox">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="profile_pic" src="workers/default.jpg" alt="Maire" />
            <h1 class="name">Maire Linke</h1>
            <p class="work"><span class="work_icon"> </span>Peakokk</p>
            <p class="mail"><span class="mail_icon">✉ </span>maire.linke@frens.ee</p>
            <p class="phone"><span class="phone_icon">✆ </span>6064 918</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="mainbox">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="profile_pic" src="workers/tanel.jpg" alt="Tanel" />
            <h1 class="name">Tanel Vimm</h1>
            <p class="work"><span class="work_icon"> </span>Teenindus- ja logistikajuht</p>
            <p class="mail"><span class="mail_icon">✉ </span>tanel.vimm@frens.ee</p>
            <p class="phone"><span class="phone_icon">✆ </span>6 979 287</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `align="center"` attribute to horizontally align `td` content without additional css.
[Here is the link](https://jsfiddle.net/1tjpnvdt/2/)